# Batch load files in AutoCAD

Tags: c#, batch-processing, autocad

I'm running into problems writing an application to batch load and export files in AutoCAD using a C#. I've received numerous errors listed below whenever I point to a folder full of .dxf files. I've been able to narrow the problem down to the point where I know it's only breaking on load. Sometimes it loads fine, others it will only load 3-4 files, and the rest of the time it will simply throw an error. The errors I'm seeing include but are not limited to  FaultExecutionEngineError, NullExceptionError, IndexOutOfRange error, and the wonderful FATAL EXCEPTION error, which causes Autocad to crash as well.

Here is my code:

```
public class MyCommands
{
    string folderPath = @"C:\Users\kdhyne\Desktop\New folder\";

    // Modal Command with localized name
    [CommandMethod("FileCycle", CommandFlags.Session)]
    public void MyCommand() // This method can have any name
    {
        var acDocManager = Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices.Application.DocumentManager;
        string[] filesInDirectory;
        Document acDoc = null;

        filesInDirectory = Directory.GetFiles(folderPath, "*.dxf", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);

        foreach (string someFile in filesInDirectory)
        {
            acDoc = acDocManager.Open(someFile);
        }
    }
}
```

I've stripped this down as far as I can think. Hopefully someone can help. Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a release build before opening it in AutoCAD and it seems to work fine! Apparently it wasn't compiling all the libraries into the debug build.